# Materialize Modal + filepicker Modal - Conflict

Tags: meteor, filepicker.io, materialize

So I use the following to load a template in a modal (something).

```
Template.something.onRendered(function(){
    this.$(".modal-trigger").leanModal();
});
```

The template has a button in it which when clicked calls the filepicker using the following code written under the templates events

```
'click #upload': function () {

        event.preventDefault();
        filepicker.pickAndStore(
            {
                mimetypes: ['image/png'],
                multiple: false
            },
            {
                access: "public"
            },
            function (InkBlobs) {
                var InkBlob = _.first(InkBlobs);
                var FilepickerId = _.last(InkBlob.url.split("/"));

            },
            function (FPError) {
                if (FPError && FPError.code !== 101)
                    alert(FPError.toString());
            }
        );
    },
```

The problem I have is the filepicker modal loads underneath the "something" modal. Because of this not only can I not access the filepicker template, if I even attempt to click anywhere outside my "something" modal,the modal will close.

Ideally, I would like to filepicker to pop up, upload image , close it, do the things I need to in the "something" modal and close it by clicking outside the modal.

Any way to avoid the clash between the two modals?

Answer (score 0):

There sure is, you need to adjust the z-index of the modals:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index